# Issues using IF AND with OLEObjects

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

`If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CBClutch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Q1"` - works correctly on its own.

`If ActiveSheet.Shapes("CMDFilter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Filter"` - also works correctly on its own.

When I run the If Statement below I get a `Run-time error '438'`. What am I doing wrong with this?

```
If ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CBClutch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Q1" And ActiveSheet.Shapes("CMDFilter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Filter" Then
    Range("B1608:L1609").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1608:$L$1714").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CMDFilter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Un-Filter"
    Range("A1604").Select
Else
    Range("B1608:L1609").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Range("A1604").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("CMDFilter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Filter"
End If
```

Comment: First of all, what's your problem? Please state. You should use `AndAlso` instead of `And`

Comment: ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CBClutch").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Q1" - works correctly on its own.

ActiveSheet.Shapes("CMDFilter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Filter" - also works correctly on its own.

When I run the If Statement I get a Run-time error '438':

Comment: THank you for your quick reply, I tried AndAlso and it gives me a compile error.

Comment: @zzzzz VBA doesn't have `AndAlso`. Oh never mind, the question wasn't tagged appropriately

Comment: @AlexSuttonMusic what kind of object is "CMDFilter" ? I'm not sure it supports `TextFrame.Characters.Text ` property

Comment: @ShaiRado - Its a simple shape from Excel.   'CBClutch' is a combo box

Comment: If I take out the OLE Object (CBCLutch) script and run it with just the CMD Filter, it works fine. As soon as I introduce the OLE Object with the AND, it fails.

Comment: the `Selection.AutoFilter` line seems a bit suspicious. you can replace it with `ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False`. Then you can use the Break In Class Module option http://www.cpearson.com/excel/BreakInClassModule.aspx and tell us on what line the error is

Comment: @ShaiRado - CBClutch is a combo box

Comment: An `OLEObject` doesn't have a `Textframe` property, so I'm a little surprised you say it works on its own.

Comment: @AlexSuttonMusic maybe you mean `...("CBClutch").Caption` ?

Comment: Thank you, have tried that and it still fails on the first line. I know the rest of the code works correctly. As mentioned before, if I take out the script And ActiveSheet.Shapes("CMDFilter").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Filter" Then
    Range("B1608:L1609").Select , then everything works correctly.

Comment: (I'm an idiot), @Rory you are correct. I had pasted from another section of code and had forgotten to change the .textframe. It now reads .object.value and it works correctly. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for your help also @ShaiRado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you code, try to assign variables to each type of `Shape` and `Object` you intend to modify or test against later. It will help you write a "cleaner" code, and also find out what properties could be modified.

In the image below, I define `Dim obj As OLEObject` , and afterwards I set it `Set obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("CBClutch")`.

So later, when I have my `With obj` statement, I can see when I click on the `.` what properties does this object has. As can be seen in the screen-shot, it doesn't have `TextFrame` - so that would return an error when checking it with an `If` later.

[image]

Comment: This is really helpful thank you, although I have a basic understanding of VB some stuff like this I am very new too! :) Thank you for your tuition! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can find the sheet [`CodeName`](http://www.spreadsheet1.com/vba-codenames.html), you can access ActiveX Controls directly:

```
If Sheet1.CBClutch = "Q1" And Sheet1.CMDFilter.Caption = "Filter" Then
    Sheet1.Range("B1608:L1714").AutoFilter 8, "<>"
    Sheet1.CMDFilter.Caption = "Un-Filter"
Else
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Sheet1.CMDFilter.Caption = "Filter"
End If
```